# Is it standard practice to use type aliases to indicate parameter semantics?

Tags: f#, tuples, naming, type-alias

Items in tuples don't have names, which means that you often don't have a clear way to document the meanings of each item.

For instance, in this discriminated union:

```
type NetworkEvent =
| Message of string * string * string
| ...
```

I want to make it clear that the first and second items are the sender and recipient names respectively. Is it good practice to do something like this:

```
type SenderName = string
type RecipientName = string

type NetworkEvent =
| Message of SenderName * RecipientName * string
| ...
```

A lot of C/C++ libraries have a proliferation of types (e.g. win32.h), but in those languages, even though parameter names are optional in many cases, it can still be done. That isn't the case with F#.

Comment: In F# 3.1, these can have names.

Comment: @JamesMoore Yeah, that makes me happy :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that using type aliases for documentation purposes is a good and simple way to document your discriminated unions. I use the same approach in many of my demos (see [for example this one](https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/blob/master/Talks%202011/F%23%20Tutorial%20(QCon%20London)/Checkout/Domain.fs)) and I know that some people use it in production applications too. I think there are two ways to make the definition more self-explanatory:

**Use type aliases:** This way, you add some documentation that is visible in the IntelliSense, but it doesn't propagate through the type system - when you used a value of the aliased type, the compiler will treat it as `string`, so you don't see the additional documentation everywhere.

**Use single-case unions** This is a pattern that has been used in some places of the F# compiler. It makes the information more visible than using type-aliases, because a type `SenderName` is actually a different type than `string`  (on the other hand, this may have some small performance penalty):

```
type SenderName = SenderName of string
type RecipientName = RecipientName of string
type NetworkElement =
  | Message of SenderName * RecipietName * string

match netelem with
| Message(SenderName sender, RecipientName recipiet, msg) -> ...
```

**Use records:** This way, you explicitly define a record to carry the information of a union case. This is more syntactically verbose, but it probably adds the additional information in the most accessible way. You can still use pattern matching on records, or you can use dot notation to access elements. It is also easier to add new fields during the development:

```
type MessageData = 
  { SenderName : string; RecipientName : string; Message : string }
type NetworkEvent = 
  | Message of MessageData

match netelem with
| Message{ SenderName = sender; RecipientName = recipiet; Message = msg} -> ...
```

Comment: Based on the up-votes this is probably a minority view, but the verbosity of records or single-case unions is a deal-breaker in my mind. It entirely negates the terseness/syntactic convenience of unions. This seems like a problem best solved by Intellisense--provided there was a way of annotating the fields--not changing your types and coding style.

Comment: I think this (otherwise excellent) answer may need an update. You can now do `type X = Msg of Sender:string * Recip: string`. And you can use these fields too: `let x = X(Sender = "Foo", Recip = "Bar")`. Just like records, but with different syntax.

Answer (score 6):

I've read my fair share of F#, both on the internet and in books but have never seen anyone use aliases as a form of documentation.  So I'm going to say it's not standard practice.  It could also be viewed as a form of code duplication.

In general a specific tuple representation should only be used as a temporary data structure within a function.  If you're storing a tuple for a long time or passing it between different classes, then it's time to make a record.

If you're going to use a discriminated union across multiple classes then use records as you suggested or keep all the methods scoped to the discriminated union like below.

```
type NetworkEvent =
    | Message of string * string * string

    static member Create(sender, recipient, message) =
        Message(sender, recipient, message)

    member this.Send() =
        math this with
        | Message(sender, recipient, message) -> 
            printf "Sent: %A" message

let message = NetworkEvent.Create("me", "you", "hi")
```

You can use [records in pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx#sectionToggle11), so tuples are really a matter of convenience and should be replaced by records as the code grows.

If a discriminated union has a bunch of tuples with the same signature then it's time to break it into two discriminated unions.  This will also prevent you from having multiple records with the same signature.

```
type NetworkEvent2 =
    | UDPMessage of string * string * string
    | Broadcast of string * string * string
    | Loopback of string * string * string
    | ConnectionRequest of string
    | FlushEventQueue
```

into

```
type MessageType =
    | UDPMessage
    | Broadcast
    | Loopback

type NetworkEvent =
    | Message of MessageType * string * string * string
    | ConnectionRequest of string
    | FlushEventQueue
```

Answer (score 1):

I think In this case you would be better off using a record type for the first two elements of the tuple to reinforce the fact that the order matters.

For numbers, you can do something slightly more elegant using units of measure, but this doesn't work for strings

Comment: Wouldn't a proliferation of records be just as bad -- if not worse, if there are a lot of `NetworkEvents`? The type inference gets really confused when there are tons of records with similar parameter names, and you end up having to fully qualify every single field.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka -- actually the situation isn't quite that bad. If you fully qualify the first field that you mention when instantiating the record, the others will resolve correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with this, but it might get annoying having 10 aliases for `string`, for example. If that doesn't bother you, I say, go ahead. Personally, I wish something like the following was supported:

```
type NetworkEvent =
| Message of SenderName:string * RecipientName:string * string
| ...
```

Then Intellisense could offer some help. (EDIT: Vote on this suggestion [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2466064-allow-optional-naming-of-union-fields).)

If your cases have more than a few fields, or several of the same type, you might consider using a class hierarchy instead.

Comment: Yeah, there are a ton of aspects of the F# syntax that just make it impossible to have as rich an IntelliSense as C#.

Comment: There's a recent improvement that allows this - "As of F# 3.1, you can give an individual field a name, but the name is optional, even if other fields in the same case are named."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx